# How to trigger lazy loading on a navigation property?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, lazy-loading

How much do you have to "touch" a navigation property to assure lazy loading of a collection?

I am using Entity Framework 5.0 with lazy loading turned on. Consider a simple class:

```
public class MyResource
{
    string name {get;set;}
    public virtual ICollection<ResourceEvent> ResourceEvents{ get; set; }
}
```

When I set up a "foreach" on the collection, I want to avoid individual retrieval of each object in the collection.

```
using(context = new MyDBContext)
{
    MyResource aresource = context.MyResources.Where(a=>a.Name==myname).Single();

    //now I want to lazy load the ResourceEvents collection
    if(aresource.MyResources!=null) // will this load collection?
    {
        List<ResourceEvent> alist = aresource.MyResources.ToList();//or must I add this?
        foreach(ResourceEvent re in alist)// (or in aresource.MyResources)
        {
        //do something
        }
    }
}
```

I know I can use Include(), but assume the MyResource object comes from somewhere else where we don't know whether collection has been retrieved or not.

Answer (score 1):

You can load collections this way:

```
context.Entry(aresource).Collection(p => p.MyResources).Load();
```

For single references use `Reference()` instead of `Collection()`.

Comment: Thanks, I understand there are ways to eager and explicit load. My question was whether checking for null will lazy load the collection?

Answer (score 0):

Accessing the navigation property will enumerate the collection which means EF will load all the entities at that time - not one by one.  This is important to know because if, let's say, you want the first entity, and you write `areasource.MyResources.First()`, EF will load all entity objects for that collection even though you're only planning on using one. `aresource.MyResources` will enumerate the collection AND THEN the `First()` operation will be performed.

To avoid that, you want to get the IQueryable for that navigation property and build on that.  For the example I mentioned, you would do the following:

```
context.Entry(aresource).Collection( c => p.MyResources ).Query().First()
```

This statement will only retrieve the one entity from the DB and not all the entities in the navigation property collection.

Comment: So checking for null will load the collection and the additional code:

List<ResourceEvent> alist = aresource.MyResources.ToList()

is not necessary. Correct?